# Answer deleting everything before first comma

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Hopefully this is the right place to bring this up; I don't get to the meta site too often.

For some reason, when I answer a question, everything before the first comma gets deleted. Just now I was answering [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/23722/10394), which began `Hi hebbo, and welcome to...`, and I found that it was in fact starting `and welcome to...`.

I did some experimentation, and found that the bug only occurred when the comma was in there. I was able to post the answer with the proper content and no comma, but I figured I should post the bug here.

I do recall this happening recently in a previous answer. At that time I thought it was just an isolated incident and found a way around it.

I do not at this time know if it is on my end or on SE's end. I have confirmed that the bug occurs on both Chrome and Firefox, so it seems unlikely it's on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm testing the bug on the meta site. If this answer didn't begin with `Hi viewer,` then you know that the bug affected this answer as well.

Yep, happens here too.

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's a deliberate feature. Salutations and valedictions are broadly discouraged across SE (for being "noise"),  and when the software can detect a salutation, it will automatically remove it. For instances where the software can't or didn't detect such things, users are explicitly encouraged to edit them out of any posts where they appear, manually.

Comment: I see. I'd like to welcome the guy, especially if it's a new user, but I guess that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @DanBron Do you know if a feature deleting things like "Hope that helped!" and signatures is planned?

Comment: Honestly it seems like we should just let the answerer say what he wants to say. If he wants to greet the user or wish him luck, why on earth can't he? It's a combined five words at most. Hardly chatter.

Comment: @CerisestHilaire This is [the Meta.SE post that outlines this policy and notes how the software implements it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/273503). Short story is that valedictions (things at the end) are too difficult to identify definitively and so are left alone to avoid inadvertently damaging posts. And Thomas, I'm personally in the camp that a little noise summed up over tens of thousands of posts is a lot of noise, and that we're a Q&A site, not a forum, but even if that view is dead wrong, it's technically policy....